# Mathematica matrix diagonalization

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I'm considering a matrix A such that A=PDP^-1.

The way I solve this using Mathematica is:

```
a={{0, -1}, {-1, 0}}
d = DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[a]]
{{-1,0}, {0,1}}
p = Transpose[Eigenvectors[a]]

p.d.Inverse[p]
{{0, -1}, {-1, 0}}
```

Which is correct.

Problem is, the P matrix is not what I expected it to be. The matrix that Mathematica generates is

```
p={{1, -1}, {1, 1}}
```

But I am looking for

```
p2={{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2])}}
p2.d.Inverse[p2]
{{0,-1}, {-1,0}}
```

Which also solves the equation. Is there a way for me to force Mathematica to show me different answers when executing Transpose[Eigenvectors[a]]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is normalize the answer you get. There is a function called [Normalize](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normalize.html), which can be used like this:

```
Normalize /@ {{1, -1}, {1, 1}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great! I am still learning how to use Mathematica, and sometimes I am not quite able to find the answers to my questions by searching on google. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You could normalize your eigenvectors:

```
a = {{0, -1}, {-1, 0}};
d = DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[a]];
p = Transpose[Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[a]];
```

so `p` is what you want:

```
{{1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eigenvectors can be freely rescaled by a constant, which means there are an infinite number of possible eigenvectors. Naturally, Mathematica cannot and will not show you all of them. So you'll need to normalize the eigenvectors in some way.

One option is to convert your matrix to numeric form using `N`. Mathematica returns normalized eigenvectors for numeric matrices.

```
p2 = Transpose[Eigenvectors[N[a]]]
```

This is risky, though, because computing the inverse of a numeric matrix can often fail spectacularly due to various numerical errors.

The other, better option is to manually normalize the eigenvectors using `Normalize`. You'll have to apply it to each eigenvector in the list returned by the `Eigenvectors` function:

```
p2 = Transpose[Normalize/@Eigenvectors[a]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider a built in matrix factorization tool?  Of course, there are many matrix factorizations, many of which are built in to Mathematica.  The one that likely corresponds most closely to your situation is `JordanDecomposition`.  Here it is in action

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {4, 4}];
{s, j} = JordanDecomposition[a];
Column[MatrixForm /@ {s, j}]
```

[image]

```
Chop[s.j.Inverse[s] - a]
```

[image]

Of course, many matrices are not diagonalizable but, if it is, then the Jordan decomposition will give you what you want.  The vectors are normalized in the same way that the `Eigen` functions normalize them, but I fail to see why this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I want the normalized vectors because I'm modeling chemical phenomena and the normalized vectors are the ones I get when solving the problem by hand.